# performing multiple word searches in one regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I have a line,"**Boy**25e6 was angry so he stole a car from **girl**37b6 and was arrested by cop58c9".
I want a regular expression to obtain the numbers only from **boy** and **girl**.

I could do

`if re.search("boy([0-9,a-f]+),", line) or re.search("girl([0-9,a-f]+)", line):`

Is there anyway to fit these two regular expressions into one?

Comment: You don't need a ',' in [0-9,a-f]+ just use [0-9a-f]+. A ',' in there means it will also match a ','

Comment: If you use a comma it will match "Boy25,e6" this term also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do `(boy|girl)([0-9a-f]+)`

Comment: remove the ',' from [0-9,a-f]+

Comment: you'll need `re.IGNORECASE` otherwise you won't match against `Boy25e6`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way to do this is to use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) from the [**re**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Boy25e6 was angry so he stole a car from girl37b6 and was arrested by cop58c9"
>>> f = re.finditer(r'((?:boy|girl)\w+)', s, re.I)
>>> f
<callable-iterator object at 0x7fb3821e3190>
>>> for m in f:
...     print m.group(1)
... 
Boy25e6
girl37b6
```